# What is the least awarded badge?

Tags: support, badges

Does anyone know what the *least awarded* badge is?

**How many times it has been awarded?**

Comment: Why not just scroll through http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges and check for yourself? There aren't *that* many different badges.

Comment: my bad , ask a stupid question...

Answer (score 8):

Excluding [gold tag badges](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold), of which 5 are completely unique, the single *rarest* badge on SFF:SE is the [Illuminator Badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/138/illuminator) which has only been awarded to one (awesome) user.

> Edit and answer 500 questions (both actions within 12 hours, answer
>   score > 0).

---

Three badges have never been awarded ([Tenacious](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/34/tenacious), [Unsung Hero](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) and [Stellar Question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/51/stellar-question)). As regards the first two, while it may be *mathematically possible* to get them, on a site with traffic this high it's deeply unlikely that anyone will actually get them.

The third one (Stellar) is closest to being achieved by [In what order should the Star Wars movies be watched?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1520/in-what-order-should-the-star-wars-movies-be-watched) & [What order should Asimov's Foundation series be read in?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/what-order-should-asimovs-foundation-series-be-read-in).

---

If you want to see the current badge counts, they're [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)

Comment: How on earth did you get that badge? The mind boggles.

Comment: Not in the ***same*** 12 hours.

Comment: @KyloRen you are not the first person I've seen misinterpret that badge, it probably need to be reworded. To get the badge, you have to edit and answer the same question within a 12 hour period; you then have to repeat that process 499 more times within 499 other, possibly different, 12 hour periods.

Comment: @KutuluMike - Yup. Badly worded.

Comment: @KutuluMike, ahh, now I see. Yes, please reword that.

Comment: @KyloRen - He can't. You'd need to raise it on Meta Meta.

Comment: @Valorum, OK, it must be the same for all of Stack then?

Comment: @KyloRen - I believe so.

Comment: Re Tenacious/Unsung Hero: I don't think "high traffic" is quite the right way of putting it.  I got both of those badges with relatively little deliberate effort on SO.  It's more like this: scifi.SE is in a "goldilocks zone."  If it had higher traffic, some things would drop off the front page before anyone could vote, and if it had lower traffic, some things might not get voted on at all.

Comment: @Kevin - In fairness it's also about culture. Out of several thousand posted answers, I don't think I've got any that are accepted but have zero votes.

Comment: Like @Kevin I got "Tenacious" and "Unsung Hero" quite easily on Stack Overflow. I agree that it is about culture; users on SF&F are comparatively generous with their votes.

Comment: "one (awesome) user" - *cough cough*, primarily opinion-based ;-)

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I thought I'd slip that one in there along with the post edit.

Comment: @Valorum You sneaky Strunk and Whiter, you.